# Implicitely pipe resolve and reject in chained then calls

Tags: jquery, typescript, es6-promise

I'm writing a lot of code with Promises in Typescript with chained `.then` calls that look like this:

```
aFunc(originalT: T) {
    return new Promise((resolve:any, reject: any) => {
        this.otherFunc(originalT).then(
            newT => this.yetAnotherFunc(newT).then(
                resolve,
                reject),
            reject);
    });
}
```

My question is, since I just pipe resolve and reject through, is there a way to write this function without doing it explicitly?

Note: I cannot use async/await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the internal promises.  This will chain them together so the original returned promise won't resolve until the inner promise resolves:

```
aFunc(originalT: T) {
    return this.otherFunc(originalT).then(function(newt) {
        return this.yetAnotherFunc(newT);
    });
}
```

It's also an [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) to create a promise and then do `.then(resolve, reject)`.  You can almost always just use the promises that are already being created by your functions and return some derivation of them rather than create a new promise like you were doing.

P.S. I don't know typescript so if I've goofed up the typescript syntax, you can hopefully see the idea from what I've shown here.

Comment: So this will call reject on the outer promise if any of the chained calls fails?

Comment: @Asik - Yes, if any place in the chain hits a reject, it immediately aborts further processing and the outer promise gets rejected.  If all resolve successfully, the outer promise ends up with the final state from the last promise in the chain.